# URL Shortener random id not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails newbie and am having an issue with with Rails shortener app I am trying to write.

I am following a tutorial on Youtube for this app at:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q67bJ0yC2SM

Can someone help me understand the flow control from the new action to the create?  I am not understanding how the new action, entering data into the form and the create action is working.

I set a binding pry in the new action.  At the time when the program hits the binding.pry this is what is stored in the params. At the time the new action is hit, nothing has been entered in the form for the original id.

```
    17: def new
    18:   @url = Url.new
    19:
    20:   letters = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z')].map { |l| l.to_a }.flatten
    21:   @url.random_id = (0...8).map { letters[rand(letters.length)] }.join
  => 22:   binding.pry
   23: end

[1] pry(#<UrlsController>)> @url.random_id
=> "ogEJCcHm"
[2] pry(#<UrlsController>)> @url.original
=> nil
[3] pry(#<UrlsController>)> params
 => {"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"urls"}
[4] pry(#<UrlsController>)>
```

After exiting the binding pry the form is now loaded on localhost:3000 and I then enter an address into the form.

When it hits the next binding pry the program now is in the create action and the original url is now set and the random_id is = "".

I tried moving the letters and the @url_random_id from the new method to the create and then get an error message.

undefined method `random_id=' for nil:NilClass

Here is the code in my controller.

```
    class UrlsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @urls = Url.all
    end

    def show
       url = Url.where(random_id: params[:id]).first

    if url
       redirect_to url.original
    else
      render 'new'
      end
    end

   def new
      @url = Url.new

     letters = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z')].map { |l| l.to_a }.flatten
     @url.random_id = (0...8).map { letters[rand(letters.length)] }.join
     binding.pry
   end

    def url_params

       params.require(:url).permit(:original, :random_id)
    end

   def create
     binding.pry
     @url = Url.new(url_params)
     #binding.pry
     if @url.save
       redirect_to urls_path
     else
      render 'new'
    end
   end

end
```

I have the following in my routes file:

```
    Urly::Application.routes.draw do
    root :to => redirect('/urls/new')
    resources :urls, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :create]
    end
```

I have the following in my new.html.erb file:

```
    <%= form_for @url do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :original %> : <%= f.text_field :original %>
    <p>
    <%= f.hidden_field :random_id, :value => @url_random_id %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.submit "Shorten my Url" %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide in helping me understand what I am doing wrong.

Let me know if you need any additional information about what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
<%= f.hidden_field :random_id, :value => @url.random_id %> # note the dot, to match what you set in the controller.
```

Then when you submit the form to your `create` action, you will have access to `params[:url][:random_id]` which will have the value of whatever was in the hidden field when the form is submitted:

```
@url = Url.new(params[:url]) # contains params[:url][:random_id]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  It seems that the @random_id will always be 8 characters regardless of the length of URL that is entered in the form. If the algorithm was set to 5 characters instead of 8 the length of the shortened URL would always be 5 instead of 8. Is that correct?  Thank you for the prompt response. Appreciate the help!